# Angular=How to edit mat-option?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, mat-select

I am working on a mat-select,.
There I have added an edit button(icon) where I want to add a function that, when a user clicks the edit button they will be able to edit the option name.
So far, I was able to keep the mat-option drop-down open when someone clicks the edit button, and open the input field. Now the problem I am stuck with is, the input should only open for the selected option and not for all at once.
This is my code:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
  <mat-select
    [(ngModel)]="selectedFoods"
    (selectionChange)="onChange(selectedFoods)"
  >
    <mat-option
      *ngFor="let food of allfoods; let i = index"
      [value]="food.value"
      style="height:5rem"
      [disabled]="checked"
    >
      <div
        style="display: flex; justify-content:space between;"
        *ngIf="!checked"
      >
        <p>{{ food.viewValue }}</p>
        <a
          (click)="onEdit(food.value, i)"
          style="margin-top:1rem;margin-left:3rem"
        >
          <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div style="display:flex" *ngIf="checked">
        <input [(ngModel)]="editOption" />
        <button>Save</button>
      </div>
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

```
selectedFoods: any;
  editOption: any;
  checked: boolean;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.selectedFoods = this.allfoods[0].value;
  }

  allfoods: Food[] = [
    { value: 'steak-0', viewValue: 'Steak' },
    { value: 'pizza-1', viewValue: 'Pizza' },
    { value: 'tacos-2', viewValue: 'Tacos' },
    { value: 'pasta-3', viewValue: 'Pasta' },
  ];

  onChange(ev: any) {
    console.log('changes =>', ev);
  }

  onEdit(ev: any, index: any) {
    console.log('edit =>', ev);
    console.log('index =>', index);
    if (ev.length) {
      this.checked = true;
      this.editOption = ev;
      console.log('This edit is triggered');
    }
```

This is the stackblitz [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-5nxtb6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fstyles.css,src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: You need to save index instead of a boolean `checked` e.g. [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hfecjv?file=src/app/app.component.ts). Example not finished but idea is there

Comment: @AndrewAllen Thanks man! This should do it for me.

Answer (score 1):

As @AndrewAllen said you can't use just *checked*. My approach is a list of boolean:

In your.component.ts

```
  onEdit(ev: any, index: any) {
    console.log('edit =>', ev);
    console.log('index =>', index);
    if (ev.length) {
      this.checked[index] = true;
      this.editOption = ev;
      console.log('This edit is triggered');
    }
  }

  savedOption(index: number) {
    console.log(this.editOption);
    this.checked[index] = false;
    this.allfoods[index].value = this.editOption;
  }
```

In your.component.html:

```
    <mat-option
      *ngFor="let food of allfoods; let i = index"
      [value]="food.value"
      style="height:5rem"
      [disabled]="checked[i]"
    >
      <div
        style="display: flex; justify-content:space between;"
        *ngIf="!checked[i]"
      >
        <p>{{ food.viewValue }}</p>
        <a
          (click)="onEdit(food.value, i)"
          style="margin-top:1rem;margin-left:3rem"
        >
          <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div style="display:flex" *ngIf="checked[i]">
        <input [(ngModel)]="editOption" />
        <button (click)="savedOption(i)">Save</button>
      </div>
    </mat-option>
```

In stackblitz a complete example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9ymto7

Comment: can you explain what happened in `this.checked[index] = true;` I didn't get it

Comment: I linked you a complete example on stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9ymto7. The core concept is *this.checked* is now an Array 1 to 1 to your *this.allfoods* array. So ***this.checked[index] = true*** make *true* just the element of i-index

Comment: Also, there is another issue that is happening that I mentioned about in the question. I am able to edit other option names. Its either I should be unable to edit other options when I select one or if a user can select all the options, the input fields should be populated with options in their respective indexes

Comment: Have you tried the example on https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9ymto7?

Comment: Yes. Do this, click the edit button of all the option and see what is shown in the input field